# Discord bot in python, check if a user is in a channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def solodab(context):

user = context.message.author
channel = user.voice_channel

if user == channel:  

    author = context.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

    print("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)


    await vc.disconnect()

else:

    print("Dab")
    await client.say("User is not in channel: ")
```

I'm making a solosnipe bot, but i would like to make it so if someone is writing this it should give a message to the person telling them to join the channel. But i don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue, i need to add a try/except block. And some if statment's

```
if voice_channel == None:
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
if server == author:
    await client.say("This just needs to be here dabdab")
else:
    try: 
        vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
    except:
        await client.say("You are not in a channel, join one!!" + author.mention)
```